# Vue3: is it possible to import a HTML file with components in it to a SFC

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a Form-Component (SFC) that should import a HTML file with Vue components in it.

**Form-Component**

```
<template src="../../../views/form-settings.html"></template>

<script setup>
import Button from "./../ui/button/Button.vue";
</script>
```

**HTML File (form-settings.html)**

```
<div>
     <Button>test button</Button>
</div>
```

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
},
```

The HTML file gets loaded correctly but the Button-Component in it not. So I get the error:
*[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Button
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.*

Comment: Try to rename it `BaseButton` instead of `Button`

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I renamed it to `BaseButton`, but the error keeps the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the problem myself.

I had to import the components I want to use in the HTML file in app.js and then initialize them with Vue.

```
import BaseButton from "./components/ui/BaseButton.vue";
app.component("BaseButton", BaseButton);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes it is possible.

You can even import the script and style section:

```html
<template src="./template.html"></template>
<style src="./style.css"></style>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

[Read it in the docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-spec.html#src-imports).

---

I don't know why your code doesn't work, I tried to create a similar demo and it works fine. [See it here on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-o8n4eg?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! yes, I saw that in the Docs. I now recreated your example in my app and I got still the same error. Do you think this is related to webpack?

Comment: @HannesA it could be. It could also be that you probably use an older version of Vue. Maybe it's an issue that's already fixed

Comment: no, i have the latest Vue version. I updated my question with my relevant package.json packages.

Comment: But I got an error like: *Single file component can contain only one <template> element*